# statsmodel adfuller() function running for too long

Tags: pandas, statsmodels

I have time series data where I have  a value for each minute. I applied `.diff()` on it with a lag of 1440 (This way I am taking the difference between values 24 hours from each other).

I am trying to test if the data is stationary using statsmodel's `adfuller()` but I am not sure how to specify the right lag (1440) because setting maxlag = 1440 seems too high.

```
    results = dataframe.diff(lag)
    for i in range(1,2):
        ...
        series = dataframe[column_name]
        result = adfuller(series.tolist()[:-1],maxlag = 1440)
         ....
```

Answer (score 0):

`maxlag` doesn't mean the maximum amount of look back that the test considers. Test will consider the whole series, but the procedure of ADF requires a maximum lag internally when it forms a model on its own (see e.g. [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test#Testing_procedure)). If you are unsure about the amount of lag, you might let the [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller.html) choose it by not specifying a `max_lag` yourself.

Comment: Normally max_lag should be smaller than the sqrt of the sample size.  The default in statsmodels is even more conservative. 

There is a better ADF test in the `arch` package (`arch.unitroot.ADF`) that has an option called `low_memory` that is much faster if you really want a big `max_lag`.